# PDO Transaction inserting ? instead of value?

Tags: php, pdo

Here is the snippet of code:

```
$pqry = $dbcon->prepare("INSERT INTO pr_users VALUES (NULL,'?','?',MD5('?'),MD5('?'))"); 
$dbcon->beginTransaction(); 
$pqry->execute(array($qryfields['email'],$qryfields['pw'],$qryfields['pw'],$qryfields['pw'].time())); 
$lastID = $dbcon->lastInsertId();
$dbcon->commit();
```

Which inserts the row as:

```
? | ? | hashed value of ? | hashed value of ?+time()
```

Should I be using `:key` instead?

Comment: On a side note: only hashing a password with MD5 is not enough; use a password hashing library like bcrypt instead.

Comment: What the code does not show, is that the passwords (and all other fields) have been sanitized, and the passwords have already been 2-way encrypted with a custom library. So we are already hashing an encrypted string. Thank you for the catch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need the quotes around the placeholders:

```
$pqry = $dbcon->prepare("INSERT INTO pr_users VALUES (NULL,?,?,MD5(?),MD5(?))");
```

They make PDO think you want the string `'?'` rather than the placeholder behaviour.

This isn't explicitly stated in the documentation, but it's fairly clear from the examples [on the manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php).

Comment: Well that was easy! Thanks. As soon as the 15 minutes is up I will mark as solved.

Comment: Maybe I should have read a bit more of the docs, now that I see all the examples you are right, it seems very clear. Woops!